# How to retain listbox selected items values on multiple clicks?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
for (int i = 0; i < lboxavilableInsName.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (lboxavilableInsName.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        if (!arraylist1.Contains(lboxavilableInsName.Items[i]))
        {
            arraylist1.Add(lboxavilableInsName.Items[i]);
            arrUpdatedInsValues.Add(lboxavilableInsName.Items[i].Value);
            arrUpdatedInsNames.Add(lboxavilableInsName.Items[i].Text);                          
        }
        ViewState["UpdatedInsValues"] = arrUpdatedInsValues;
        arrUpdatedInsValuestotal = (ArrayList)ViewState["UpdatedInsValues"];
        ViewState["UpdatedInsValues2"] = `enter code here`arrUpdatedInsValuestotal;
        ViewState["UpdatedInsNames"] = arrUpdatedInsNames;
    }
}
```

Actually I have given `selsectionmode="Multiple"` in the listbox. That will select me multiple items when I select first time or subsequent time after page gets loaded, but I want that in a code behind saying ex: if I select 2 items 1st time that 2 items will added in the second listbox and I will get the values of those selected items.

If again I select any items after adding previous selection items in 2nd `listbox`, I want the item value selected at 2nd time along with first two item values. So totally 3 values I want. and I need to send that values to the stored procedure to insert.

Comment: There is a `SelectionChanged` event on ListBox control, you can use it to control what items selected, and update your second list from `SelectedItems` property. But that'll be better to bind data to `SelectedItems` and make all logic at VM.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are assigning new values each time to the 2nd listbox, you don't need to assign them, you need to add values within your 2nd listbox, in this way your 2nd listbox will retain all the previous and the new values as well.
Hope it helps.